# Extending Qml in python : named signal parameters

Tags: qt, pyqt, qml, pyside

According to Qt's doc :

> All Qt signals on a registered class become available as special "signal properties" within QML to which the user can assign a single JavaScript expression. The signal property's name is a transformed version of the Qt signal name: "on" is prepended, and the first letter of the signal name upper cased. For example, the signal used in the example above has the following C++ signature:
>
> signals:
>        void partyStarted(const QTime &time);
>
> Signal parameters become accessible by name to the assigned script. An unnamed parameter cannot be accessed, so care should be taken to name all the signal parameters in the C++ class declaration. The intrinsic types listed in Adding Types, as well registered object types are permitted as signal parameter types. Using other types is not an error, but the parameter value will not be accessible from script.

"so care should be taken to name all the signal parameters in the C++ class declaration" => How do i do that in python ?

I need this in my attempt to translate this custom C++ extension : http://qt-project.org/doc/note_revisions/44/221/view (WheelArea) into some python/PySide or PyQt code :

So far, i'm almost good, but i can't figure how to translate this part (the wheel event signals) :

```
signals:
    void verticalWheel(int delta);
    void horizontalWheel(int delta);
```

in python (the named signal parameters) to access the delta from qml.

Comment: According to Pyside's doc, it's a PySide.QtCore.int (http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QGraphicsSceneWheelEvent.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QGraphicsSceneWheelEvent.delta)

And python identifies it as a <type 'int'>

Comment: @QuidNovi did you ever find a solution to this question?